# Visual Studio 2013 License Product Key

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, licensing

I installed Visual Studio 2013 Professional as a Trial version while waiting for my company to complete the license purchase.

They completed the purchase of 4 licenses (64 bit), but were not given `Product Keys`. Instead, there is a particular `.iso` file with the license or product key embedded in some way.

I want to avoid having to uninstall Visual Studio 2013 only to reinstall Visual Studio 2013 and re-setup all my settings.  Is this possible? Is there a way to extract the license/product key from the `.iso` or from other coworkers desktops that did a clean install?

Here is what I have tried (with 2 coworker installations):

1. Looking for the license info in:

   `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Licenses\*`

   but it is unique on both computers.
2. Looking for the Product Key in:

   `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Registration\2000.0x0000\PIDKEY`

   One install had one, which my install said was invalid when attempting to use it. The other install had a blank `PIDKEY`.
3. Looking inside `SW_DVD5_Visual_Studio_Pro_2013_English_MLF_X19-20996.ISO` but I see no mention of a License or Product Key.
4. Checking their `Help > Register Product` in Visual Studio, which simply says

   > License: Product key applied
5. Tried doing an install/repair from the ISO but it says:

   > The product version that you are trying to set up is earlier than the version already installed on this computer.

   Likely because of the [Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 and 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42666)

Again, I would really like to avoid the multi-hour process of reinstalling VS 2013. Is there any way?

Comment: Don't think there is a way to get the license key but if you just install the ISO it should just update your trial version and leave all your settings and other tools/installs intact.  Should take less than hour.

Comment: @ScottWylie tried that, but didn't work because of new service packs. updated question to not repeat here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined within the scope of the Help Center. This question should be addressed by Microsoft Support.

Comment: This should be migrated to SuperUser.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I solved this, without having to completely reinstall Visual Studio 2013.

For those who may come across this in the future, the following steps worked for me:

1. Run the ISO (or `vs_professional.exe`).
2. If you get the error below, you need to update the Windows Registry to trick the installer into thinking you still have the base version. **If you don't get this error, skip to step 3**
   [image: "The product version that you are trying to set up is earlier than the version already installed on this computer."]

   - Click the link for 'examine the log file' and look near the bottom of the log, for this line:
     [image: Detected related bundle ... operation: Downgrade]
   - open `regedit.exe` and do an `Edit > Find...` for that GUID. In my case it was `{6dff50d0-3bc3-4a92-b724-bf6d6a99de4f}`. This was found in:

     > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{6dff50d0-3bc3-4a92-b724-bf6d6a99de4f}
   - Edit the `BundleVersion` value and change it to a lower version. I changed mine from `12.0.21005.13` to `12.0.21000.13`:
     [image: BundleVersion for Visual Studio]
     [image: lower the version for BundleVersion]
   - Exit the registry
3. Run the ISO (or `vs_professional.exe`) again. **If it has a repair button like the image below, you can skip to step 4**.

   [image: Visual Studio Repair button]

   - Otherwise you have to let the installer fix the registry. I did this by "installing" at least one feature, even though I think I already had all features (they were not detected). *This took about 20 minutes.*
4. Run the ISO (or `vs_professional.exe`) again. This time repair should be visible.
5. Click `Repair` and let it update your installation and apply its embedded license key. *This took about 20 minutes.*

---

Now when you run Visual Studio 2013, it should indicate that a license key was applied, under `Help > Register Product`:

[image: License: Product key applied]

Hope this helps somebody in the future!

[Reference blog 'story'](http://johndelizo.wordpress.com/2013/12/23/visual-studio-2013-setup-blocked-the-product-version-that-you-are-trying-to-set-up-is-earlier-than-the-version-already-installed-on-this-computer-fixed/)

Comment: it took 4 hours for repair to complete and solved nothing, however registering a product with newly created Microsoft account extended my licence for additional 74 days :)

Comment: Had this exact issue after VS15 SP 1 RC broke my installation. Your fix worked great (regedit)